# GPIO Access on Cortex-M4 : Read-Modify-Write vs Atomic

Tags: gpio, cortex-m, cortex-m4

I recently came across the Bit-banding feature on Cortex-M4 core and how it provides a solution to avoid race-conditions while toggling bits of registers.
The M4 also has a dedicated BSRR register for performing atomic bit manipulation on the GPIO ports,I understand that using this makes the application thread-safe

Is there any downside to this approach compared to the generally used Read-Modify-Write method of toggling GPIO pins.If not, then why are GPIO_ODR registers provided for the cortex-m cores, why not use only the BSRR register for GPIO pin access.

Comment: Take this case: toggling 8 pins(can be a port altogether) at the same time? Which is faster?

Comment: @ammar.cma the BSRR/BRR *can* change up to 16 bits at a time if they are in the same port.  But what these registers can't permit is transferring *arbitrary* data with an efficient fixed instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assume that all operations on IO ports are at bit level. I wrote an external LCD interface a while ago that used Px0..Px7 for the data interface, and Px8 for the write control. This allowed me to directly stream a pixel (16-bit colour) to the display using a sequence of four GPIO_ODR writes. If I had used BSRR I would have had to translate the raw pixel data into bit masks for that register. This would have slowed things down significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the particular MCU in question, but the BSRR register is specific to ST Micro Cortex-M parts.

The BSRR register provides similar functionality to the bit-banding feature that is part of the Cortex-M architecture with regards to atomic operation.

As for whether bit-banding has a downside compared with doing read-modify-write, the main drawback is that they can only manipulate one bit at a time.

Comment: Note that unlike address-based bit banding, the BSRR and BRR *do* permit multi-bit operations, as they operate with bitmasks.

Comment: The GPIO ports that Arm licenses with the Cortex-M have a mask built into the port address, so you can do an atomic write of the port bits with a single operation.   The only vendor that I'm aware of that use the Arm GPIO design is TI, although NXP does it in a similar way.   Energy Micro/Silabs has ports with set/clear registers.